(Combinatorics) How many ways are there to go to the opposite vertex of a cube of length n
See this picture for reference

You want to go from red to green. You can choose, for each step, from Forward, Up, Right, only. You must also only walk on the surface of the cube. (Say after going Up, then Right, you cannot go Forward on your 3rd step) How many different ways are there?
One observation is that if we remove the constraint on only walking on surface, the problem becomes very easy. However, I couldn't find a reasoning to "un-count" the ways violating the constraint. It seems to be an entirely new problem.

You can only walk on two faces.  There are six choices for which two.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317288/moving-on-the-surface-of-a-cube?rq=1

No, @Empy2, not if $n$ equals, say, 18.

@JosephExpo Thank you.

What is the length of a step?  If you can take steps of any length there are an infinite number of ways.  Presumably you have to follow the lines, but you didn't say that.
